# How we update our app from free Version to Paid Version?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

currently i am having the app that has lot of functionality and it is available free for users on Appstore but i want that the user can upgrade the same app to paid version to view more functionality ? How we do this

PLZ Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can update your app which is currently on appstore and in that update you can include inAppPurchase for the item you need to lock so this way your app will be there in appstore and with the feature of free and paid version ;)

Answer (score 0):

So you need to add new update to your app and in this version you need to directly add your app as a paid app...

Comment: go to itunes conncet add new version of your app...

Comment: No i want to provide the functionality to the user to update from free to paid version that are already on Appstore

Comment: are you looking for inApppurchase.

Comment: yeah Hope if this problem can we resolved by using In App Purchased

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the only way is to release free update with all the new features initially locked, but can be unlocked with in-app purchases.

The other way is to release full paid version of your app and share data between free and paid version.

Comment: Can u plz explain me the other version?

Comment: As i understood from your comments to other posts, you wanna give additional functionality to your user after payment. So just create update with locked features that user can unlock with in-app purchase. you can create non-consumable purchases. It will allow your user to get features on all his devices.

Comment: No I want that user switch from free to paid version (i don't want any unlocking)?

Comment: What data do you want to share between paid and free version? If there is no data, I don't see any trouble. Simply offer your user to buy full version of the app using standard UIAlertView.